# How to catch the number of an error in JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, try-catch

I am a beginner.

I don't know How to catch the number of this error in JS with a try-catch, I'm lost.

```
Uncaught (in promise)
no: 6, message: "PNG driver doesn't support data type Int16. Only e…bit (UInt16) bands supported. Defaulting to Byte\n"}
message: "PNG driver doesn't support data type Int16. Only eight bit (Byte) and sixteen bit (UInt16) bands supported. Defaulting to Byte\n"
no: 6
```

Please, Help Me :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question post the code that is causing this error, and show us how you used `try`/`catch`. We can't help you without that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bergi here is a part of my code, i want to catch the error to change options[] params :
      `try {
        options = [
      '-of', 'PNG'
      ];

     
      GDAL.gdal_translate(tifDataset, options).then((output) =>
      {
        
        GDAL.getFileBytes(output).then((bytes) =>{
          base64Data = btoa(bytes.toString().split(',').map(c => String.fromCharCode(c)).join(''));
        });
      });
      }`

Comment: @kakou What is `GDAL`? Please [edit] your question to include the code with proper formatting

Comment: And yes, you cannot handle asynchronous errors (promise rejection) with `try`/`catch` unless you use `async`/`await`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await. This question is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102365/why-is-try-catch-not-working-with-async-await-function

Comment: @Bergi GDAL is a librairy. It allows me to convert TIFF images to PNG.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your answer I'll try ```async```/```await```. I hope it works