# Why I'm not able to catch this error in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I can't catch an error in my React app.

I have a **Context** and in the **Provider** I have the following function

```
const signIn = async (data: string) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.post(`url`, { data })
    setUser(res.data)
  }
  catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err)
    throw new Error("something went wrong")
  }
}
```

Then I'm calling the function.

```
try {
  auth.signIn(data)
} catch (err: any) { // this catch doesn't work
  console.log(err)
}
```

When I call it like that, the console log in the catch of **signIn** runs, throws the **Error** and the catch where I'm calling the function doesn't catch and everything blows up. Like I don't have a catch when I'm calling the function. (in the second example)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try logging the return value of `aut.signIn(data)` and you'll understand what's happening

Comment: `Then I'm calling the function.`,  if this is inside a component, without say using `useEffect`, then React will just freak out yes.  Although I think there it;s now possible Server Side components in next to mark a component as been `async`, and then you could `await`, and then the `useEffect` is not required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is try {} .. catch() not working with async/await function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68102365/why-is-try-catch-not-working-with-async-await-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is because `auth.signIn(data)` is an asynchronous function and you're not waiting for it to complete before moving to the catch block in the second code snippet.

To resolve this, you should use await when calling auth.signIn(data). This ensures that the Promise is either resolved or rejected before executing the catch block.

Note: You must ensure that the function where you are calling auth.signIn(data) is an async function, so that you can use the await keyword.

Here's an example:

```
const someAsyncFunction = async () => {
  try {
    await auth.signIn(data);
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it may be a problem with the asynchronous behavior of 'signIn'.

Try using 'await' in the 'try - catch' block. Something like this may work:

```
try {
  await auth.signIn(data); // Use await here to catch any errors
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

You may want to modify ur 'signIn' function instead to return the promise generated by 'axios.post'.

```
const signIn = (data: string) => {
  return axios.post(`url`, { data }).then((res) => {
    setUser(res.data);
  });
};

// Calling your code
auth.signIn(data)
  .then(() => {
    // Success right here
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    // Handle the error here
  });
```

Hope it helps bro :)